# Android service running in background without sleep?

Tags: android, service

i'm doing a location grabbing service for my phone.
The main activity sets some timing like 10min interval which results in the servicing running polling both gps and network location for the first 1 min then post the result in http then rest for the 9mins. 
The questions is, does the service get destroyed in deep sleep? if thats the case i'll have to use alarm manager for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not destroyed, it is sleeping. When you wake your phone up it must continue working and getting location updates.

You need to use `AlaramManager` or `WakeLock`

Comment: this post is kinda old. @Olegas would you share code snippet on how to use AlarmManager or WakeLock?

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9408496/how-to-prevent-my-app-to-go-sleep-mode) may this help

Comment: Also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322643/run-a-service-in-the-background-forever-android