# How to prevent my app to go sleep mode.

Tags: android

My android application is not working when user does't used his/her phone for long hours. rite now for this problem user should touch a my application icon it will restart after this the application works fine.

Is my application will go to sleep mode when user does't used phone for long hours? If yes then how to prevent this in android.

Comment: I request to select answer to mark as accepted if your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK,
 "My Tag");
wl.acquire();
```

screen will stay on during this section..

when exiting from app..donot forget to call

```
wl.release();
```

Mention permission

```
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Answer (score 0):

use PowerManager `final PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
         mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
        mWakeLock.acquire();`
and also check the links [PowerManager.WakeLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html) and [power management](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/development/pdk/docs/power_management.html)