# Get screen on/off event while application is not running

Tags: java, android, android-event

I am currently trying to figure out, how to get the screen on/off event in android. Currently, it works as long as my MainActivity is runnig. But as soon as I close the activity, somehow Sevice and the Receiver stop working aswell (I don't get any Log messages anymore). I guess the problem, is somehow related to the dynamicaly registration of the receiver. As soon as the application gets closed, the receiver gets unregisted (?). How can I keep the receiver alive? (It is not possible to declare the receiver in the Manifest file).

I got the following code:

Main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ScreenOnOffService.class));
    }
}
```

ScreenReceiver:

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    Log.e("test","onReceive");
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
        Log.d("test","Screen Off ");

    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
        Log.d("test","Screen On ");}
    }
}
```

ScreenOnOffService:

```
public class ScreenOnOffService extends Service {

//Some unimportant code
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);
    final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="ch.ethz.inf.thesis.screenonoffproject.app.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".ScreenOnOffService">
    </service>

</application>
</manifest>
```

Am I missing something to keep my service alive? I hope somebody can help me out.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713361/keep-a-service-running-even-when-phone-is-asleep).

Comment: Hey Steve, i guess this doesn't solve my problem (if i am not missunderstanding something): The problem is not that my service stops running during sleep events, more that the receiver doesnt work anymore. I guess after closing the application it gets unregistered.

Comment: Hey Steve again, Sorry i was wrong. It did help me alot :D

Answer (score 0):

try with full path in service and reciever if any

```
<service  
android:name="ch.ethz.inf.thesis.screenonoffproject.app.ScreenOnOffService">
</service>
```