# How to show a dialog box in three days once in an android application betfan

Tags: java, android, dialog, sharedpreferences

here Before displaying the dialog check the preferences to get the time that it was last displayed. If it's been more than three days, display the dialog and set a new time in SharedPrefs.

here is my code but it crashed my app , pls tell what i am missing here

```
long time = sharedPrefs.getLong("displayedTime", 0);
if (time < System.currentTimeMillis() - 259200000) {
displayDialog();
prefsEditor.putLong("displayedTime", System.currentTimeMillis()).commit();
}
```

Comment: How do u get ref to the `SharedPreferences`?

Comment: Please share the `exception` thrown ?

Comment: please write me some code @searching

Answer (score 0):

You are actually looking for [JobSchedular](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html)

and See this you can get some idea on how to implement it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713361/keep-a-service-running-even-when-phone-is-asleep)