# How can I run Android process in standby?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, android-wake-lock, recognizer-intent

I want to continue my Android SpeechRecognizer intent when the user pressed the power button to lock the screen.

```
public abstract class ListeningActivity {
    protected SpeechRecognizer sr;
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    sr.startListening(intent);
```

But currently, when locking the display, the process stops. How can I continue the SpeechRecognizer correctly?

Comment: go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713361/keep-a-service-running-even-when-phone-is-asleep

Answer (score 0):

no way！android system will kill app all in 5 minute when you locked the dispaly unless your app join Wihte-list.OR,user allow to app running in backgroud

Comment: This should be a comment.