# Need code example on how to run an Android service forever in the background even when device sleeping, like Whatsapp?

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, background-process

I have tried various ways to achieve this, but my service eventually gets killed.

I want to use AlarmManager to trigger a class every one hour. Even if the device is sleeping, it should sent a flashing LED alert, vibration or sound. In any case, it should run forever.

I have noticed that Whatsapp is always running, even though I kill all the running apps and clear the memory, put the device to sleep, and still Whatsapp receive messages and alerts me. How are they doing it? I want to do the same with my app.

Comment: You need something similar to a _partial WakeLock_. Please have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8713795/824495) answer, and the comments.

Comment: it depends on how you are running your service. Would you like to post  `onStartCommand` of your service?

Comment: Seçkin M., this is exactly what I am doing. However I can go in the Active Applications and see my app there. Here I kill my app, which kills the AlarmService along with it, stopping everything. However there is a long list of applications which show in the Running Application tab, which don't get stopped, including Whatsapp, facebook, netflix, even my Tetris game, which is probably looking for ads to display all the time. Are they using Wakelocks? Or there is something else which they do which I am not aware of? There is cetainly something which I am missing here. Is it really Wakelock?

Comment: @zeeshan Did you find any solution? How did you implement your service finally?

Comment: Yes, I did, and have been using them for a long time very successfully. Check my answer below. And up vote too if it helps you :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run a service in the background forever..? Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322643/run-a-service-in-the-background-forever-android)

Comment: But that question's accepted answer is pretty useless: where is the code to show how to do it?

Comment: I've posted a pretty clean nifty solution here. Hope it helps.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029040/how-to-run-an-android-app-in-background/43555050#43555050

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**NOTE: NOW THIS ANSWER IS ONLY VALID FOR ANDROID 7 AND BELOW. SINCE ANDROID 8 GOOGLE HAS CHANGED HOW BACKGROUND TASKS ARE HANDLED**

Since I posted this question, I have implemented two different approaches to this solution into multiple apps.

---

> **APPROACH 1**

This extract is from an app where I use push notifications, which need instant wake up calls for the device. Here what I do is

1. use WAKE_LOCK permission and
2. use a Wakelocker abstract class
3. use it in an Activity as needed:

**Manifest:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

**WakeLocker class:**

```
public abstract class WakeLocker {
private static PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;

public static void acquire(Context context) {
    if (wakeLock != null) wakeLock.release();

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |
            PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |
            PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "WakeLock");
    wakeLock.acquire();
}

public static void release() {
    if (wakeLock != null) wakeLock.release(); wakeLock = null;
}
}
```

**Activity class example:**

```
private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Waking up mobile if it is sleeping
        WakeLocker.acquire(getApplicationContext());
        // do something
        WakeLocker.release();
}
```

---

> **APPROACH 2**

Best when you want to give Android control over wake up, and can live with periodically waking up your code. Simply use an AlarmManager to invoke a Service class at regular intervals. Here is some code from my LifeLog24 app:

**MainActivity**

```
Intent ll24 = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiverLifeLog.class);
    PendingIntent recurringLl24 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, ll24, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarms.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, first_log.getTime(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR, recurringLl24); // Log repetition
```

**Alarm Class**

```
public class AlarmReceiverLifeLog extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "LL24";
    static Context context;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.v(TAG, "Alarm for LifeLog...");

        Intent ll24Service = new Intent(context, LifeLogService.class);
        context.startService(ll24Service);
    }
    }
```

and LifeLogService.class is where I do my stuff. Alarm wakes up every hour in this case and triggers the BroadcastReceiver which in return runs the service. There is more to it, to make sure service is not run twice and so on, but you get the point how it is done. And AlarmManager is actually the best way to do it since you don't worry about battery usage, etc. and Android takes care of waking up your Service at regular intervals.

Comment: Yupp approach 2 is the way to keep your service working.

Comment: can you give a full example please..?

Comment: @Vishal It is two years old answer and and things have changed significantly in the Android world since I had posted this answer. I don't have any piece of code to give you as a complete example.

Comment: @zeeshan can u please help me. I am using ionic 2.i need create a backgroud service in android.How to create service

Comment: @ANISUNDAR I am sorry, I don't have any experience with Ionic.

Comment: @SadeepDarshana the app I used this code in is still using it and working fine. I still use AlarmManager/Service combo for similar background tasks. It is simple and works perfect.

Comment: Hey Zeeshan, why doesn't the AlarmManager die with the service? If we register it with MainActivity, what keeps it running?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia its an Android OS level system service and you cannot stop it or kill it. The OS keeps it running. Many OS services depend upon it. However, With Android O, things have changed and you should look if Alarm Manager would work the same way for your particular case.

Comment: Hey Zeeshan, so I tried all of that and for some reason nothing is working. Do you mind looking at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51460417/why-does-android-keep-killing-my-service

Comment: @RuchirBaronia unfortunately at this point I won't be able to help you due to lack of time, plus I haven't done any Android O related updates to my own app either. When I'll do update to my own app, I'll update this answer as well, but I don't think it will be soon.

Comment: Alarmmanger will not work if you are looking for above Oreo OS. This is the best answer for below OS 8 but not work well and Always for newer OS versions.

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'first_log', please help i am new in android development.

Comment: @RohitNishad unfortunately this answer is not valid for Android 8 and above.

Comment: @zeeshan  so what i use to run service forever

Comment: @RohitNishad now you cannot run Service forever. Google has restricted it due to security reasons. Look into JobScheduler. Google has made it complicated, confusing and doesn't provide any good examples or documentation to learn it. You are on your own basically here. Start by looking examples on Foreground Service and JobScheduler.

Answer (score 11):

It is very simple.
steps:
1.create a Service class.
2.create a BroadcastReceiver class
3.call BroadReceiver in **onDestroy** method of service
4.In **onReceive** method of BroadReceiver class start service once again.

Here's the code

**Manifest file:**`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".LauncherActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service
        android:name=".utilities.NotificationService"
        android:enabled="true">

    </service>

    <receiver
        android:name=".utilities.RestartService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="RestartServiceWhenStopped"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="RestartService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

`

**Service class**

```
public class NotificationService extends Service {
    public NotificationService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
       super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
       return START_STICKY;
   }

   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy();
       Intent restartService = new Intent("RestartService");
       sendBroadcast(restartService);
  }
}
```

**BroadcastReceiver class**

```
public class RestartService extends BroadcastReceiver {

     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

         context.startService(new Intent(context,NotificationService.class));
     }
 }
```

Comment: how i implement it in my code i created these classes and added code in manifiest and now what should i do ?

Comment: you need to start your service using startService() method.

Comment: onDestroy is not guaranteed to be called if the system is low on resource

Comment: Do not use this answer, onDestroy is not always called when the system is terminating services.

Comment: @VigneshVRT can it work if I use `this.startService(myIntentService)`  inside of `onDestroy` method.

Answer (score 2):

Follow these easy steps to keep servce alive forever in android device.
1. Call a service by using alarm manager.
2. return START_STICKY in onStart method.
3. In on destroy call the alarm manager and restart service by using startService method.
4.(Optional)Repeat the point number 3 in onTaskRemoved method.

Answer (score 1):

Request partial WakeLock.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

 PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
mWakeLock.acquire();
```

onStartCommand retrun START_STICKY :

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId); 
        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

Comment: This will drain the battery. There is something else which Whatsapp and Skype use, they don't put any noticeable strain on battery.

Comment: are there any other alternatives?

Answer (score -1):

You can use a function startForeground(int, Notification) [see here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ProcessLifecycle) and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29)

> A started service can use the startForeground(int, Notification) API
>   to put the service in a foreground state, where the system considers
>   it to be something the user is actively aware of and thus not a
>   candidate for killing when low on memory. (It is still theoretically
>   possible for the service to be killed under extreme memory pressure
>   from the current foreground application, but in practice this should
>   not be a concern.)

Comment: eVEN IF THE NOTIFICATION IS THERE, THE SERVICE WILL STILL GET KILLED