# What is the best way to have a push notification server and send data between android device and server?

Tags: android, parse-platform, socket.io, google-cloud-messaging

I want to write a program in which user can have something like chat in it.
Actually we have a forum in which  user can ask questian and if someone answers this question we want to send notification for questioner!
Http Request seems good but I think this is not good if we have many users(50K for example) and every 30 sec we send http request to server from online users.
I don't want the project to take a long time so I don't want to implement and write socket between android app and server myself. I find GCM but it only works when user have logged in Google account as far as I know.
I also saw 'Parse.com' but I don't know if we can use this push notification service as push notification in Parse.com ; As far as I know Parse.com is manual and this is not feasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For android Device some good options are GCM, Amazon SNS , Urban Airship.

Till yet Parse was the best option for me but they are discontinuing their service in 2017, so its not a good option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Service` and you can run it in background after define intervals.

For help how to run service forever in background look at this link:[Need code example on how to run an Android service forever in the background even when device sleeping, like Whatsapp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19345008/need-code-example-on-how-to-run-an-android-service-forever-in-the-background-eve)

Comment: I know! I think you don't understand my question because of my bad description! i want library or service like GCM. the main problem is with server! and I want write a MVP so i don't want spent too much time on it.

Comment: httprequest must write on background too. but this is not good if 5k device every 30 sec ask from server: "what's up?"!!! so i think we need socket and i know we must write it on background. do you know any open source server or client?